# How to delete particular element of structure type in a list?

Tags: c++

how to delete only 5 no element

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct fcfs
{
    int process_no;
    int burst_time;
};

int main()
{
    list<fcfs>lst;
    list<fcfs>::iterator it;
    struct fcfs pro;
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        pro.process_no=i;
        pro.burst_time=i*10;
        lst.push_back(pro);
    }
    it=lst.begin();
    while(it!=lst.end())
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\n",it->process_no,it->burst_time);
        it++;
    }
    //lst.remove(5);
    it=lst.begin();
    while(it!=lst.end())
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\n",it->process_no,it->burst_time);
        it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: See: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102)

Answer (score 1):

To erase items from list, you need to give the iterator value of 5th element and use `erase` function to remove,  like `lst->erase(itr)`

And use `lst.remove(itr)` also to do the same thing. As `remove()` is an inbuilt function in C++ STL which is declared in header file. remove() is used to remove any specific value/element from the list container. It takes the value which is passed as a parameter and removes all the elements with that value from the list container. And for struct type element removing you need to give the iterator.

For getting the iterator of 5 no element try this,

```
itr = lst->begin(); // itr is pointing the first element of list
// now increment `itr` four times to get the 5 number element's iterator
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) itr++;

// now use `itr` to remove the element which is pointing by itr
lst->remove(itr);
// or erase it
lst->erase(itr);
```

as from the comment you can use this instead manual loop:

`auto itr = std::next(std::begin(lst), 5);`

Comment: @Ashik Sazal hope you get it

Comment: it's not working. i want to delete only 5 no element

Comment: @Ashik Sazal i have updated my answer, have a look

Comment: I recommend `auto itr = std::next(std::begin(lst), 4);` instead of manual loop.

Comment: @eerorika thanks for your comment, i have added this also in my answer

Comment: @AshikSazal Accept the answer, it is more appreciable